# Break UILabel into 2 lines with separate background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY0Ve.png

I want my text on lines but with separate background. How can i achieve this using UILabel ?

I tried padding etc but nothing works it just show single red box if i select background color for label.

Any help on how to get same effect like image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.yourLabel.text];

//EDITED
[text addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length/2)];
[text addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor orangeColor] range:NSMakeRange(text.length/2, text.length/2)];

[self.yourLabel setAttributedText: text];
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code and it says incompatible point address NSString to NSAttributedString

Comment: It crashes on launching

Comment: Hi, Thanks it works :)
But not what i am looking for... i want two different background color if line separates into 2. Not different color for text.
Any idea what i must try ??

Comment: @user1859651 Use `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` as I have edited now. Also, you will need to implement a logic to find how many characters are there in each line and then modify the `range` of the color attributes.

Comment: Thanks.. will look more into it. But i was looking for the logic that help to give separate background

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSAttributesString`. Create a `UILabel`, create an `NSAttributesString`. Then instead of using `setText` of label, call `setAttributedText` using the string object you created earlier.

More help on [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/attributedText)

Answer (score 0):

```
[mutableAttributedString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:selectedRange];
```